# socket emit to nodejs server

Tags: node.js, sockets, go

I have a Node.js server with socket.io listening on port 4000. I've been able to make javascript version to work just fine and emiting to the socket. Also, I have a Go application that is making some calculations and to emit data from Go server to Node.js.

I wanted to use sockets for this since it needs to happen in realtime but for some reaseon can't figure out how to just emit socket event from Go server to Node.js server.

Any idea how to accomplish this. Here is my Node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

// App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('listening for requests on port 4000,');
});

// Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('join', function(data){
        console.log('get join');
    });

});
```

And inside my Go application when I get this endpoint I want to emit to the Node.js server

```
mux.GET("/socket", SendSocketRequest)
func SendSocketRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
 // emit to the Node.js app
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot guarantee it will work i did not test this code. But it can looks like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {

    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", "localhost:4000")
    checkError(err)

    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)

    _, err = conn.Write([]byte("Some data written to the server\n"))
    checkError(err)

    result, err := ioutil.ReadAll(conn)
    checkError(err)
    fmt.Println("Result is: ")
    fmt.Println(string(result))

    os.Exit(0)
}
```

You should read more about TCP connection. This is simple struct which has ability to `Write` to or `Read` from the socket.

Please see more examples here and analyse the code: https://golang.org/pkg/net/